# How to add a horizontal line in iOS using StoryBoard?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uiview, uiviewcontroller

In my app I am trying to create a customized/stylish horizontal line in-between two labels. I have searched in SO and Google but it has only by code. How to add a horizontal line using story board?

In **Android** I have designed the below line using XML.

[image]

How can I create the same line in **iOS**?

Comment: I don't see what's so difficult or vague about this question. This has to be one more time I'm seeing casperOne on a rampage. One way to make a quick horizontal rule is by placing a 1px high empty label with an appropriate background.

Comment: Totally agree with Bijou. This casperOne should really try starting to read a question before giving his judgement.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You just have 2 options:

- take an image with the appropriate gradient and insert an image view
- make yourself a view class, that fills it's view with a gradient (by code)

That's it

Comment: If you're you're making a prototype, in a rush, or using Agile, a quick trick from the good ole' days is just to create a label of underscores or dashes and color appropriately; e.g., __________________________________________________________________ -------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Another "trick" if you can't be bothered to do any of the above (pure laziness I know) would be to use a thin progress bar set to whatever colour you want, with a progress of 0.

Comment: Yet another but easier "trick" is to use an empty UILabel with its height set to 1px and set its background color and width to your preference. Hope this helps.

Comment: @programmer is easiest. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Use "View" and set its height as 1 or any size you want, and change the background color.

Answer (score 5):

In Storyboard, if you don't want code. I recommend following process.

> 1. draw a line using a drawing tool (about illustrator, photoshop) and
>      then saved as png.
> 2. make a UIImageView your Storyboard and set image your png file.

Comment: thanks for your answer.. is is possible by code if so i am happy to do that as well